# created a model in blender, imported into Unity and not affected by light

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, light

I created a hand model in blender, imported it into my scene in Unity and it does not get affected by my lights.

I created some seam lines and unwrapped the thing. I have other elements that I created in a similar way and the only difference I can appreciate here is that this one is not a mesh renderer, it is a skinned mesh renderer, because it has bones inside.

This is how it looks like, you can see the "torch light" focusing to it, making a round of light, and the hand is getting weird lights, like only the reflected light from below or something.

[image]

Those are the settings of the mesh

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the normals are wrong. You can try to invert normals in blender or change the import settings (in Unity) of your hand mesh to calculate normals instead of using the normals in the blend file ([See normals & tangents section here](http://docs.unity3d.com/401/Documentation/Components/FBXImporter-Model.html)).

Comment: I noticed that normals are actually inverted, in blender they are NOT. If I invert them in blender (they look wrong in blender) I get a nice shape in Unity. But the lightning keeps being the same ugly

Comment: hmm... try to export with a different file format. it did the trick in Maya >> Unity project.

Comment: The normals being wrong when imported into Unity is a problem I've seen *constantly*.  I don't know why it happens, only that inverting it (or letting Unity calculate it) will (usually) solve the problem.  Some applications are better about the exported file than others.

Comment: @javirs: what happens if you change your import settings of the mesh to 'calculate' normals instead of 'import' normals?
Could it be that the normals are not normalized? I'm not a modeller, my knowledge is very basic, but I have already seen assets where the length of a normal would be 0.1 instead of 1, which would break any light calculation (could have something to do with the scaling in Blender).

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely an issue with normals. Something wrong is going on during exporting probably.
Try Calculate option under Normals in Importer settings

[image]

Hope that helps.